# Error while reading metadata in LLVM IR

Tags: metadata, llvm, llvm-ir

I have a LLVM IR instruction as follows: `store i32 %i.0, i32* %arrayidx, align 4 !0`

Note that I attached a metadata `!0` to the instruction. And for my purpose, this represents a metadata string which I have declared as follows:

`!0 = !{!"hello"}`

Now I try to read this using

`if (Inst.getMetadata("hello"))`

However, upon executing this, I get the following error:

`opt: <stdin>:32:43: error: expected instruction opcode
  store i32 %i.0, i32* %arrayidx, align 4 !0`

Can someone please point out, what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Just posting to help anyone stuck with the same problem.
The metadata needs a name. So this works:

`store i32 %i.0, i32* %arrayidx, align 4, !my_metadata !0`